# Access to CPU time during simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I need to run simulink and set a timeout and a penalty on time out. Hence, I need a block to give me the CPU time (real world time).

[image: Real world time]

The clock block gives the simulation time:

[image: Simulink Clock block]

The CAN timeout detection is discrete and it does not work with my continuous solver.

[image: Simulink CAN timeout]

The Matlab function blocks make simulation so slow.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically using a real world clock in an (acceleralted) simulation is not a good idea.
Here is a simple example using a m-script to set a timeout. It's primarily based on [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-set-param-command.html)

```
model='untitled';
timeout=10;

set_param(model,'SimulationCommand','start')
tic;
while(true)
    if not(strcmpi(get_param(model,'SimulationStatus'),'running'))
        disp('simulation exited')
        break;
    end
    if toc>=timeout
        disp('timout reached')
        set_param(model,'SimulationCommand','stop')
        break;
    end
    pause(1);
end
```

If you don't like polling, this could also be implemented using [callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html), but this requires inserting a callback into your model.